# Can I use ArrayList in VBA without enabling .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: vba, arraylist, mscorlib

I am being asked to prepare for the disabling of .NET Framework 3.5, which appears to be necessary in VBA to use the library system.collections (ArrayLists, Queues, SortedList, etc.). Is there a way to continue to use this library without enabling 3.5? Or is there an alternative to ArrayLists available in VBA?

Comment: For your last question; it depends on your usage of the Arraylist. (a collection, ListBox, array variable  etc)

Answer (score 0):

Most of these data structures have been around for awhile (most since .NET 1.1), and are COM Visible so you can use late binding to gain access to them. Some sort of variant of .NET would need to exist on the windows machine, it needs those libraries for much of the functionality of Windows.

Give this approach a try on a machine without .NET 3.5 enabled and see if there are issues.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NETGenericCollections()
    Dim arrayList       As Object
    Dim iter            As Variant
    Dim i               As Long

    Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With arrayList
        .Add "2"
        .Add "3"
        .Insert 0, "1"
    End With

    For Each iter In arrayList
        Debug.Print "Array List iterations " & iter
    Next

    Dim stack As Object
    Set stack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")

    With stack
        .Push "1"
        .Push "2"
        .Push "3"
    End With

    Debug.Print "Stack peek " & stack.peek() 'see the item without removal
    Debug.Print "Stack pop " & stack.pop()
    Debug.Print "Stack pop " & stack.pop()

    Dim queue As Object
    Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")

    With queue
        .enqueue "1"
        .enqueue "2"
        .enqueue "3"
    End With

    Debug.Print "Queue peek " & queue.peek()
    Debug.Print "Queue dequeue " & queue.Dequeue()
    Debug.Print "Queue dequeue " & queue.Dequeue()

    Dim sortedList As Object
    Set sortedList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

    With sortedList
        .Add 3, 3 'Key, Value
        .Add 2, 2
        .Add 1, 1
        .Add 5, 1
    End With

    For i = 0 To sortedList.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "Sorted List iter " & sortedList.getkey(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

**Further reading**

[System.Collections Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections?view=netframework-4.8) - Check for ComVisible decorator, this will tell you if you can likely use this collection in your code.

[SortedList](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Sortedlist_en.html) - Some examples, a great site for VBA insights.

[Queue](https://analystcave.com/vba-queue-using-vba-queue-excel/)

[Stack](https://analystcave.com/vba-stack-using-vba-stack-excel/)

Comment: I have tried both early and late binding, but both fail when 3.5 is disabled.

Comment: Can you point to an earlier or newer version of mscorlib via Tools > References?

Comment: The only one available is "mscorlib.dll".